# Metodo findAll do doctrine retorna o mesmo id em todas as linhas

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Estou fazendo uma pesquisa que me retorna todos os dados da minha Entidade.

,

acontece que ele me retorna todos os dados mas com o mesmo id, mas verifiquei a base de dados os ids são diferentes.

.

```
$entityManager->clear();
        print_r($entityManager->getRepository('models\AlarmesNcc')->findAll());
        $entityManager->flush();
```

retornando

```
Array
(
    [0] => models\AlarmesNcc Object
        (
            [id:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => 1 /aqui nesta linha
            [criated:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => dd
            [severity:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => ssss
            [deviceService:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => ss
            [details:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => sss
            [usuario:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => 1
        )

    [1] => models\AlarmesNcc Object
        (
            [id:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => 1 /aqui nesta linha
            [criated:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => dd
            [severity:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => ssss
            [deviceService:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => ss
            [details:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => sss
            [usuario:models\AlarmesNcc:private] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi, o problema estava nas anotações do doctrine

estava desse jeito

```
/**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
```

porque quando gerei as annotation a minha table com campo id era do tipo tynint

Alterei a o id na tabela para int e mudei a annotation fazendo isto

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
```

funcionou perfeitamente